# Interesting query string - referrer (google.com) being passed in query string

Tags: google-analytics

I have recently started seeing a query string in Google Analytics that I'm trying to figure out why it's showing up.  It looks like:

```
https://example.com/my_uri/?back=https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&as_qdr=all&as_occt=any&safe=active&as_q=the+users+search+query&channel=aplab&source=a-app1&hl=en
```

The web clients are always Safari, and the `back` parameter is always `google.com`.

It's only showed up in the last couple of months.  I'm guessing that it's some kind of web application, but curious as to what it really is from.

Comment: Can you discover/reverse the IP addresses the hitsccame from for further hints?

Comment: @davidgo, good idea.  Unfortunately, I can't definitively match the request in GA with my logs.