# Unknown long phrases searched on my website reported in search console coverage

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 404, noindex, coverage

I checked my search console coverage. It seems that many long phrases are being searched on my site, and I have many noindex pages in coverage, but I have never made such a page.
is my website hacked. I don't know what to do now.
Please see the following screenshot:

[image: excluded by noindex tag]

Comment: If you visit those URLs, are they real pages on your site, or do they juts give a 404 Not Found?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller They are 404 pages.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar items that on my site.  [Interesting query string - referrer (google.com) being passed in query string](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/interesting-query-string-referrer-google-com-being-passed-in-query-string)

After watching it for several months, I  decided it was from tools that are designed to anonymize the user's data.

It's possible that your traffic is coming from a specific search functionality of the stwl dot xyz site or that their site was hacked.

Comment: Hi Trebor, Thank you for your answer. i think spammers are using a robot for search on websites and index their url on our website